# python peewee raw query without escaping characters

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

Is there any way to prevent escaping backslash in python peewee (peewee-2.8.8) ORM?

I would like to execute query in MySQL database:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS\G
```

The "\G" part is essential! I need to the results in vertical form.

The problem is that peewee always escapes backslash (\) so it ends in MySQL as:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS\\G
```

and of course MySQL issues an error:

```
 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\G' at line 1"
```

I tried to use plain "execute_sql" method:

```
cursor = RaDatabase.execute_sql('SHOW MASTER STATUS\G')
```

and also "raw" method:

```
query = BaseModel.raw('SHOW MASTER STATUS\G')
result = query.execute()
```

but both ended with escaping characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a "raw" string?

```
cursor = RaDatabase.execute_sql(r'SHOW MASTER STATUS\G')
```

For what it's worth, whatever you pass in to .execute_sql() is essentially handed over to the MySQL driver (pymysql, or whatever you're using). Peewee itself does not do any escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it didn't work either :)
But you are right that peewee does not do any escapes.
I did some network sniffing and query was sent exactly as peewee got it.

I just misunderstood the "\G" option - it is not MySQL database engine option, it is option to mysql client program.
When mysql client sees "\G" option it sends "normal" query to MySQL db but formats (internally) results to be vertical.
So my solution was to send plain 'SHOW MASTER STATUS' to MySQL db and format results from cursor to be vertically presented.

BTW, thank you very much for peewee!